# PubSub with jQuery

Tags: jquery, publish-subscribe

How does PubSub really works? Suppose I have a button that can show or hide an specific div. If I open the same URL in different windows or tabs, I want the events to sync. I have not done this before and PubSub is a tad bit scary. Is there like a stand-alone Library for it without installing lots of packages? Can you guys point me to the right direction and please don't not just say "Google It Up" because that's why I am doing for the last 5 hours.

```
$(document).on("click", ".mybutton", function () {
    if ($(".mydiv").hasClass("hide")) {
        $(".mydiv").removeClass("hide").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
var evt = {};
$(document).on("click", ".mybutton", function () {
  $(evt).trigger('buttonClick');
});

$(evt).on('buttonClick',function(){
   if ($(".mydiv").hasClass("hide")) {
        $(".mydiv").removeClass("hide").show();
    }
});
```